# Репликация SQL Server в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, репликация

Есть база данных `MSSQL` и `PostgreSQL`. Необходимо синхронизировать данные, находящиеся в SQL Server, с базой данных `PostgreSQL`, а именно, 3 таблицы, причем, их структура в двух базах данных немного отличается. Синхронизация - односторонняя (т.е. данные, которые добавляются / редактируются / удаляются в таблицах `MSSQL`, должны также попадать в `PostgreSQL`, но не наоборот). Какими способами можно реализовать такую синхронизацию?

Первое, что пришло на ум - создание бэкграунд-процесса, который будет с заданным периодом выгружать измененные данные из `MSSQL` и сохранять их в `PostgreSQL`. Но у такого подхода есть один минус - нет гарантии, что в определенный момент времени данные полностью синхронизированы.

Далее начал искать в гугле и наткнулся на репликацию. Однако не нашел готового решения для репликации `MSSQL -> PostgreSQL`.

Еще наткнулся на CLR-триггер, но на эту тему крайне мало нашлось информации с примерами кода.

Хотел узнать мнение сообщества, как обычно решается такая задача

Comment: Идея - вообще не репликировать, а доступать как foreign table через [odbc_fdw](https://github.com/CartoDB/odbc_fdw) (по принципу Single Source of Truth).

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Как вариант - неплохо. Но ведь этот способ предполагает то, что `psql` будет запрашивать данные, правильно я понимаю? Или как работает этот механизм?

Comment: Да, идея такая. Postgres будет запрашивать данные как "свои". К сожалению имею опыта как это сделать с Oraсle или с внешными файлами, с MSSQL - нет.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm тогда это почти ничем не отличается от обычной выгрузки данных через бэкграунд-сервис. Разве что ваш способ будет несколько быстрее. В идеале - нужно на триггер изменений в таблице SQL Server'a посылать данные в Postgres.

Comment: Отличается только тем, что _нет копия_ данных и во всех случаях консистентность сохранена. Не помню откуда эта цитата, но нравиться, "Лучший способ послать данные - никуда их не посылать", т.е. Single Source of Truth.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm А, вот оно что :) Т.е. эта Foreign Table будет как ссылка на таблицу в SQL, понял